# Tag Synonyms: [dating], [romance], [marriage] & [sex] → [relationships]

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, tag-synonyms

I'd like to request that [dating](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dating), [romance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/romance), [marriage](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marriage) & [sex](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex) be preemptively made synonyms of [relationships](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relationships) as this will help people searching in this domain.

I'd suggest them directly, but I keep [having problems doing so](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2316/tag-synonyms-vote-restriction).

Comment: How exactly will it help with searching?

Comment: @MatthewRead if you were to type in [tag:romance] as a tag, you wouldn't see any results, so you wouldn't think there was anything on the subject.

Comment: So for normal tag-entering rather than searching the site.  I can see the reasoning, but I don't think they're really needed preemptively.  There are probably a few synonyms you could create for every single tag (at least, ones that aren't game names) and that would just get out of hand.

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, I really don't see the need for this particular tag. Pretty much all relationships/marriage/booty-seeking quests are counted as a [side-quest](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/side-quest) in relation to the main story in games that have these options. We already have a tag for that, and it is a synonym for [quest](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quest).

I doubt anyone is going to be searching for *only* [relationships](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relationships) related questions, and anyone searching for such questions regarding the sidequests within a subset of tags should be able to find it under [quest](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quest).

Comment: I search for only relationships-related questions...:(

Answer (score 1):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Our tagging system has changed drastically since this post's inception; it no longer makes sense to have a broad [relationships](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relationships) tag on questions.

Instead, if a game's relationship system is a big enough topic area that it warrants it's own tag, consider creating a [game-name-relationships](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-name-relationships) sub-tag (substituting 'relationships' for whatever the game calls it).